# Borrar y mostrar inputs si el checkbox esta pulsado/o no pulsado

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo una iteración de colores convertidos en checkbox:

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-colores" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-colores-tab">
  @foreach ($colores as $item)
    <div class="checkbox text-center">         
       <input type="checkbox" id="colores_{{ $item->id }}" class="obtener_color" name="colores[]" value="{{ $item->name }}" data-id="{{ $item->name }}"/>
       <label class="label-cliente" for="colores_{{ $item->id }}" style="background: {{ $item->color }}"></label>
       <div class="name_colores">{{ $item->name }}</div>
    </div>
  @endforeach
  <div class="inputsCantidades"></div>
</div>
```

Lo que necesito es que si pulso a un checkbox se muestre un input en la capa `inputsCantidades`, en cambio si vuelvo a pulsar a ese mismo checkbox, necesito que ese input que se ha añadido antes se elimine del DOM.

Hasta ahora consigo mostrar los inputs por cada color que pulso y me pone la id correspondiente en cada input, pero no se como hacer que se elimine el que deshabilito.

```
$('.obtener_color').bind('change', function () {
  var color = $(this).val();

  if ($(this).is(':checked')){
     $(".inputsCantidades").append("<div class=\"prueba\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"precio_und_ofe\" class=\"form-control\" id=\""+ color +"\"></div>");
  }else{
     $('.inputsCantidades', this).parent('div').remove();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He simplificado un poco tu código y alterado el HTML para eliminar las partes donde se usa el motor de plantillas que esté usando el framework que usas. De esta manera puedo hacer un ejemplo bastante similar al código que estás usando.

Básicamente lo que hago es añadirle al HTML del input que añades al DOM el color obtenido del `value` del checkbox con el que se ha interactuado. De esta manera el input inyectado ya tiene el color al que pertenece. Para ello me valgo de un atributo personalizado `data-color`.

Si el checkbox se selecciona inyecto la estructura HTML necesaria en el DOM, si se deselecciona busco al input que tiene el `data-color` que corresponde al valor del checkbox con el que se interactua, selecciono su padre y lo borro.

```js
$('.obtener_color').bind('change', function () {
  const color = $(this).val()
  const estructuraHtmlColor = `
    <div class="envoltorio-color">
      <input type="text" name="precio_und_ofe" class="form-control" data-color="${color}">
    </div>
  `

  if ($(this).is(':checked')){
     $(".inputsCantidades").append(estructuraHtmlColor)
  } else {
     $(`.inputsCantidades input[data-color="${color}"]`).parent().remove()
  }
});
```

```css
input[data-color="verde"] {
  background-color: green;
}

input[data-color="azul"] {
  background-color: blue;
}

input[data-color="rojo"] {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-colores" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-colores-tab">
    <div class="checkbox text-center">         
       <input type="checkbox" class="obtener_color" name="colores[]" value="verde" data-id="verde"/>
       <label class="label-cliente" style="background: freen"></label>
       <div class="name_colores">Verde</div>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox text-center">         
       <input type="checkbox" class="obtener_color" name="colores[]" value="azul" data-id="azul"/>
       <label class="label-cliente" style="background: freen"></label>
       <div class="name_colores">Azul</div>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox text-center">         
       <input type="checkbox" class="obtener_color" name="colores[]" value="rojo" data-id="rojo"/>
       <label class="label-cliente" style="background: freen"></label>
       <div class="name_colores">Rojo</div>
    </div>
  <div class="inputsCantidades"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Brillante, muchas gracias por todo @phpMyGuel